# Is it okay to store all Data in an Data Class?

Tags: java

Is it okay for a school project to store all Data like Variables, Objects and other stuff in one "Data Class"? Because I have heard once that you should never do something like this. Are there any other and better approaches to this topic?

Thank you. (:

Comment: I'm rather confused, give an example of the type of data, like names, passwords, emails, etc...

Comment: "Are there any other and better approaches to this topic?" What about storing it in multiple classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it okay for a school project to store all Data like Variables, Objects and other stuff in one "Data Class"?

Depends upon what that data is, but almost certainly not, because of the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle):

> The single responsibility principle states that every module or class should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by the class. All its services should be narrowly aligned with that responsibility. Robert C. Martin expresses the principle as, "A class should have only one reason to change."[1]

Only the data relevant to a specific class should be stored in that class. If it's not relevant to one class, it may be relevant to another, and so should be placed in there.

It also sounds a bit like you're describing a [God object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object), which is considered an anti-pattern:

> a God object is an object that knows too much or does too much